# Bulk API all data

Tags: api, bulk

Is it possible to extract all data from SalesForce using a API? (Bulk API in this case)? If so, what languages? I've seen xml and java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Bulk API is the most suitable for your purpose. You can find step by step instruction for connecting through BULK API in below link,

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_code_walkthrough.htm

Comment: Thanks you! Is this also possible in C#?

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to do it in C# also. It is basically working based on Partner WSDL.